# ACFoundation Cemera Zoom in Zoom out functionality

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, zooming

I am using AVFounadation to access camera features on my iPhone.I want to add zoom in and zoom out functionality on my camera view.I am able to zoom in and zoom out the preview layer but the output image and video are still normal (not zoomed).

I am using the following code on gesture event:

`[newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(zoomLevel,zoomLevel)];`

Please let me know if I am missing anything.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can Zoom only preview layer Not the original image.
So one solution is that after getting image from camera we can **crop original image** according to zoom level then save it.

**And in video zooming is Not possible**.
But solution is also there 
We can fram the video in images and set the cropping functionality for all the frames(images) and then create other video from cropped frame.